# is it possible to insert update and delete a view using hibernate with mysql as database if it possible suggest me a solution

Tags: java, hibernate

The following code is for insert delete and update data in mysql database table name is student and i created a view using this student table can i perform insert update delete operations on this view if possible suggest me how

**This code to retrieve object**

```
 package roseindia.tutorial.hibernate;
    import org.hibernate.Transaction;

    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;


    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
    public class FirstExam {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Session session = null;

    try{


    SessionFactory sessionFactory =newConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    session =sessionFactory.openSession();

    Transaction transacton =session.beginTransaction();


    System.out.println("Inserting Record");
    Contact contact = new Contact();

    //contact.setId(1);
    contact.setFirstName("Vikas");
    contact.setLastName("Kumar");
    contact.setEmail("vikas@gmail.com");
    session.save(contact);
    //session.update(contact);
    //session.delete(contact);
    transacton.commit();
    System.out.println("Done");

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    finally
    {
    // Actual contact insertion will happen at this step
    session.flush();
    session.close();

    }

    }
    }
```

**code for persistence class**

```
    package roseindia.tutorial.hibernate;


    public class Contact {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private String email;
        private int id;


        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }


        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }


        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }


        public void setEmail(String string) {
            email = string;
        }


        public void setFirstName(String string) {
            firstName = string;
        }


        public void setLastName(String string) {
            lastName = string;
        }


        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }


        public void setId(int i) {
            id = i;
        }

    }
```

**mapping class**

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="roseindia.tutorial.hibernate.Contact" table="STUDENT">
       <id name="id" type="int" column="ID" >
         <generator class="increment"/>
      </id>

      <property name="firstName">
         <column name="FIRSTNAME" />
      </property>
      <property name="lastName">
        <column name="LASTNAME"/>
      </property>
      <property name="email">
        <column name="EMAIL"/>
      </property>
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

**configuration class**

```
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://192.168.10.161/testdb</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.pool_size">10</property>
      <property name="show_sql">true</property>
      <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
      <!-- Mapping files -->
      <mapping resource="contact.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: Hibernate handles views as tables, so in your mapping file you only should have to swap the table name by the view name.
Regarding, inserts, updates and deletes in a View first you need you view support that operations. Then possibly this could work or not :P
Check here insertable and updatable views on MySQL http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: i tried with view name instead of table name it is not working it is showing as cant read mapping file

Comment: I don't really have a *definitive* answer, but **I have been able to insert** rows into a view using hibernate 4.0.3, and a MySQL view which was simply a `SELECT * FROM some_table`. YMMV